# How to put a variable into z ZeppelinContext in javascript in Zeppelin?

Tags: angularjs, scala, apache-zeppelin

In Scala and Python it's:

```
z.put("varname", variable)
```

But in javascript I get (in the console)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: z is not defined
```

What I really want to do is access a javascript variable from Scala code using `z.angular("varname")` in Zeppelin, but I'm having no luck :(

In full need in one cell something like

```
%angular
<script>
var myVar = "hello world";

// some magic code here!
</script>
```

Then in another cell

```
println(z.angular("myVar"))
```

UPDATE:

This is what I have so far, I'm completely stabbing in the dark, since I'm more of a back end / data science kind of guy. So apologies in advance for my front end hopelessness.

Cell 1:

```
z.angularBind("myVar", "myVar")
z.angularBind("msg", "msg")
```

Note I have no idea what to put in the second argument.

Cell 2:

```
%angular

<div ng-app>
    <div id="outer" ng-controller="MsgCtrl">
        You are {{msg}}
    </div>
    <div onclick="change()">click me</div>
</div>

<script>
var myVar = "hello world";

function MsgCtrl($scope) 
{
    $scope.msg = "foo";
    // also experimented with $scope.msg = myVar;
}

function change() {
    var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.msg = 'Superhero';
    })
}
</script>
```

Cell 3:

```
z.angular("msg")
z.angular("myVar")
```

And no matter what I do I just either get `null` or the var name.

I don't see a button either or anything to "click".

Answer (score 9):

**In Angular interpreter. we can**

- Use within html content

  `{{name}}`
- Bind with

  `ng-model='name'`
- Use or set with ng-click or other angular directives.

  `ng-click="name='Rockie'"`

> Modify scope variable outside of angular's controller is not a good practise according to many SOs. I also have not make it work in Zeppelin. There is a [normal js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sXkjc/8/) though.

**And in Spark interpreter. We can**

- Bind with

  `z.angularBind("name", "Knock Data")`
- Unbind with

  `z.angularUnbind("name")`
- Get the value with, the variable need be bind first, otherwise it will get null.

  `z.angular("name")`
- Watch a variable with

  `z.angularWatch("name", (oldValue: Object, newValue: Object) => {
    println(s"value changed from $oldValue to $newValue"
  })`

**Beside the angular bind. The [Dynamic Form](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/manual/dynamicform.html) is a good way to give interactive for end users**

- Input

  `z.input("number", 1).toString.toInt`
- Select without default value

  `z.select("Day", Seq(("1", "Mon"), ("2", "Tue")))`
- Select with default value,

  `z.select("Day", "1", Seq(("1", "Mon"), ("2", "Tue")))`
- Check

  `z.checkbox("good applications", Seq(("1", "Zeppelin"), ("2", "Highcharts"), ("3", "Spark")))`

Comment: Thanks I learnt a lot reading this.  So I added `<div ng-model='myVar'>` to the end of my `%angular` cell, but I'm still getting `null` for `z.angular("myVar")` in the Scala cell :(  I also tried playing with the example in the link but I just kept getting `null` for `z.angular("msg")` :(

Comment: you need z.angularBind first, then ng-model. after that you can get the value with z.angular.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to show what I have so far.

Comment: What I'm missing is how to have javascript code triggered when an angular value changes. I want to do z.angularBind("data", data) in a loop, and have my redisplay logic in javascript get triggered when data changes.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

%angular

```
<div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 50%" ng-model="id_selected_arr"/>
```

%spark2

```
var result = z.angular("id_selected_arr")
```

But I gace another issue, how to process the array... Maybe someone will answer to you and it moght help to you as well Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136609/pass-and-process-an-array-from-js-to-spark-in-zeppelin)