# Is it possible to set global variables in a Zeppelin Notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to create a multi-paragraph dashboard using a Zeppelin notebook. I'd like people using the dashboard to only have to enter certain parameters once. E.g. if I'm making a dashboard with information about different websites, the dashboard user only has to select the particular website they want information about once and the whole multi-paragraph dashboard will update. Is this possible? How do I set global variables like this in a notebook?

To clarify, the parameter input that I intend to use for Zeppelin is referred to as ["dynamic form"](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dynamicform.html).

Comment: I'm not very sure what do you mean by global variable ? A variable is shared among notebooks in Zeppelin

Comment: I think @eliasah means that a variable (e.g. : `${formName}`) is visible only within its paragraph and not across all the paragraphs of the notebook. What he means is "set once, use everywhere".

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself @marius_neo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `z.put` and `z.get` can share variable over different notebooks.

```
z.put("name", "zeppelin")
z.get("name")
```

Possibly combine with `z.angularBind` and `z.angular` to use it in dashboard. ref [How to put a variable into z ZeppelinContext in javascript in Zeppelin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335170/how-to-put-a-variable-into-z-zeppelincontext-in-javascript-in-zeppelin/38353337#38353337)

Comment: This won't work using a spark SQL interpreter, correct?

Comment: Use sqlContext.sql instead of directly write %sql shall help. Combine with z.angularWatch and z.run can even make it more dynamic. Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9SvBBXjojU

Comment: Why in hell would someone watch a video  when text is so easier to read and use and create.

Answer (score 2):

You can use notebook-level global variables in the SQL by using the syntax `$${variableName}` instead of `${variableName}`. [[Reference]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1363).

When you run one of the paragraphs that uses global variables, the global variable input fields will appear above all the paragraphs.