# Pass and process an array from JS to Spark in Zeppelin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have to visualiase some map thingy in Zeppelin via spark and JS (angular interpreter in this case). Zeppelin has [this](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/usage/other_features/zeppelin_context.html) binding feature but it gives a little knowledge about usage.

I would like to click on the button, evaluate some stuff, than send the id_selected_arr to the spark via binding.

In %angular window

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" ng-click="eval()" ng-model="id_selected_arr"/>
```

In %spark2 window

```
var result = z.angular("id_selected_arr")
```

I get: result: Object = id_selected_arr

So my questios are: Did i actually send the array via binding? And how can I process this returned object in spark, such as get elements in the passed array?

Edit: I had to use oldschool style of calling a click function :

```
<div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 50%" ng-model="id_selected_arr"/>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="eval()"/>
```

Comment: For now, I have no solution. It looks like, it is impossible to transfer data from FE to BE. I managed to execute FE script in specific pargraph, but actually it did not help me at all. So for now I have no clue how to pass an array from JS to BE spark.